# Is there any way to prevent user sessions from expiring in ASP.NET WebForms when code is edited?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

When I edit a VB file and deploy my changes to a server, all the users who are logged in to that server get logged out. However when I edit an ASPX file, this does not happen. Thus we have wound up with a bunch of ASPX files containing nothing but VB code, just so they can easily be deployed! But this confuses my IntelliSense... Is there any way to deploy changes to a VB file without expiring user sessions?

Comment: You'll need to use an external Session state store, such as SQL Server or ASP.NET's out-of-sproc session server. That said, it's often a bad idea to use `Session` for anything important (and don't use it for storing user information that should go inside `ClaimsPrincipal`)

Comment: You can also upload you changes when less people are using your site... Or advertised your changes: "Site will be down at noon for 15 minutes"...
That's just a suggestion... ;-)

Comment: Hmm, according to web.config we are using SQL Server for storing session state - this should prevent the issue, @Dai? I haven't actually tried to deploy anything myself; this is a legacy app and I'm going on what the previous app developer told me about why he's got VB code in ASPX files... maybe this question is moot?

Comment: Careful - moot means *debatable*. Most people don't know that. : )